# affine transformations, strategy for finding invariant straight lines

Tags: affine-geometry

At first lets introduce some notation.

$\mathcal{A}^n$ is a $n-$dimensional affine space and $V$ is its associated vector space. For any affine subspace of $\mathcal{M}$, its associated vector space it would be denoted as $V_{\mathcal{M}}$.

For the points of the affine space I will use bold capital letters such as $\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{P},\mathbf{R},\mathbf{A},..$ and for the vectors of $V$ bold smaii ones.

The vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ that produced by $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{P}$, it would be denoted as $\mathbf{QP}$

Finally if $S=\left\{\mathbf{O},\mathbf{A_1},\mathbf{A_2},\cdots,\mathbf{A_n}\right\}$ is a coordinate system with origin $\mathbf{O}$ then,

its associated basis of $V$ it would be the $\mathcal{B}_s = \{\mathbf{a_i} = \mathbf{OA_i}: i=1,\cdots,n\}$ and the vector $\mathbf{OX}=\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathcal{A}^n$

---

Consider a affine transformation $f:\mathcal{A}^n \to \mathcal{A}^n$, with $f(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{p}$

> What is the general strategy we follow to find the invariant straight lines under the transformation $f$?

Consider a line $\varepsilon$ parallel to $\mathbf{v}$ passing throw point $\mathbf{Q}$, so $$\varepsilon=\left\{ t\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{q}:t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

we have that $$f(\varepsilon)=\left\{ tA\mathbf{v}+A\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{p}:t\in\mathbb{R} \right\}$$

in order to be $\varepsilon=f(\varepsilon)$ it should exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$A\mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v} \text{ and }A\mathbf{q}=\lambda \mathbf{q}+\mathbf{p}$$

So the problem is, to find the eigenvalues of $A$ and their corresponding eigenvectors and then solve the equation $A\mathbf{q}=\lambda \mathbf{q}+\mathbf{p} $

Theoretically, is everything alright?

Here is a basic example:

> Consider a affine transformation $f:\mathcal{A}^2 \to \mathcal{A}^2$, with $f(\mathbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\3 &10\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}$, which is the invariant lines of the plane?
>
> using the above method we have that the eigenvalues of $A$ is $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=11$ and their corresponding eigenvectors are $\mathbf{v}_1= \begin{bmatrix} -3\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{v}_2= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\3 \end{bmatrix}$.
>
> So the invariant lines of the transformation $f$ should have the form $$t\mathbf{v}_i+\mathbf{q}_i \text{ with } i=1,2$$
>
> but how i will find the points $\mathbf{q}_i?$

---

## Edit

## _______________________

*My first try above is **wrong** but I believe that I make some progress so let me share it with you, I don't delete the former text in order for the reader follow my thoughts.*

Consider a affine transformation $f:\mathcal{A}^n \to \mathcal{A}^n$, with $f(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{p}$

and a line $\varepsilon$ parallel to $\mathbf{v}$ passing throw point $\mathbf{Q}$, so $$\varepsilon=\left\{ t\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{q}:t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

> what is the general strategy we follow to find the invariant straight lines under the transformation $f$?

we have that $$f(\varepsilon)=\left\{ tA\mathbf{v}+A\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{p}:t\in\mathbb{R} \right\}$$

*(Here is where my reasoning was wrong)*

In order to be $f(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon$ it should be

1. $f(\varepsilon)\parallel\varepsilon$
2. and $f(\varepsilon) \cap \varepsilon \neq \varnothing$

So at first we should find for which $\mathcal{v}$ we have that $f(\varepsilon)\parallel\varepsilon$. In other words we should find a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$A\mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v}$$

Once we have the find the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ and their corresponding eigenvectors $\mathbf{v_i}$, $i \in I$

We know that every line of the form $$\varepsilon=\left\{ t \mathbf{v_i}+\mathbf{q}:t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$ it is mapped throw $f$ to a parallel one.

Now for every $i\in I$ we should the following equation with unknowns the $t_1, t_2$ and $\mathbf{q}$

$$t_1 \mathbf{v_i} + \mathbf{q} = t_2 A \mathbf{v_i} + A \mathbf{q} + \mathbf{p}$$

Even this is a fare general method, the problem seems far from solved. At least in generall.

---

*The general case it seems to be too complicated but we may extract interesting results for the cases $n=2,3$*

*Many new questions have came to my mind. For example,  what happens when the eigenvalues are complex numpers? or when the $\mathbf{p}$ from the last equation belongs to a line parallel to the $f(\varepsilon)$ or..*

*I will soon add and the solution to the basic example*

*Feel free to and your thoughts, still I dont know if my reasoning is correct, moreover I am sure somewhere there is a great resource explaining our problem, so if someone know it, please share your reference*

Comment: Nice question. ${}{}$

Comment: i edited the post with some new thoughts

Comment: If you work in homogeneous coordinates, your problem becomes that of finding the two-dimensional invariant subspaces of $M=\small{\begin{bmatrix}A&\mathbf p\\\mathbf 0^T&1\end{bmatrix}}.$ This is fairly easy if $M$ is diagonalizable (or its minimal polynomial factors into linear and irreducible quadratic factors), but rather challenging when there are defective eigenvalues.